# GWT 2.4.0 and JRE 5

Tags: java, gwt

I want to use JRE 5 with GWT 2.4.0.

I know that GWT 2.4.0 has been built with JDK 1.6.

I am wondering if it has been built with compliance to 1.5 or not ?
Will it run in JRE 5 or does it require JRE 6 to run?

What I was thinking of doing is building my GWT 2.4.0 project with JDK 1.6 but setting
the compliance level to 1.5.

Any thoughts on that ?

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Actually, GWT doesn't require a JRE to run (except, if you're talking about dev mode, or maybe the few server parts of GWT). It runs on a JavaScript engine. So whatever your company rules are - maybe you can use this to get around them (reasoning: Java 6 is only needed as an intermediate step when compiling the classes to JavaScript)

Comment: Emm.  I never tried that. I've since found a AppServer with 1.6 that I can use.  I think if I was to try to follow your approach, I'd have to compile with JDK 1.6, package with 1.5 (to ensure WAR could be unpacked ok with JRE 1.5).. or I could use an exploded WAR too..  a possible solution for anyone that is really really stuck.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support in GWT 2.4 for JRE 5. In the release note from GWT 2.2 they said:

> **A note about Java 1.5** 
>  GWT version 2.2 will only have deprecated support for Java 1.5, resulting in warnings when building
>   applications. While Java 1.5 will still work for this release of GWT,
>   developers should upgrade their version of Java to correct these
>   warnings and ensure compatibility with future versions of GWT.

[Source of this Articel](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.de/2011/02/google-plugin-for-eclipse-and-gwt-22.html)

This mean, GWT 2.3 was the last version what deprecated supported JRE 5. Since GWT 2.4 you have to use Java 1.6 or above.